# Determine which algorithm is used of a specific WhiteboxTools function

Tags: whitebox-tools

I am using the WhiteboxTools function RasterToVectorLines. I would like to know which algorithm is used here but I can't find any exact information about it in the documentation or the source code. Is there an easy way to determine what this is?